# CSS doesn't seem to work in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I've got a basic PHP script embedded in a html document. I've also got an external style sheet. When I view the page, the CSS has an effect on the entirety of the page, except on an echo statement. When I test the page with some html text, the CSS works on that, yet it doesn't work when printing the variable.

This is the html/php:

```
<div id ="date"> 
test
<?php 
echo "$newDate"; 
?>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for "date":

```
#date {
color:#ff0000;
}
```

As I said, the CSS works for the rest of the page, and works when showing "test", as shown below:

[image: css not working]

The date "2016-03-15 15:43:40" should also be in red and centered, so why does this not work? Thanks

EDIT: I've got other classes in my CSS (is that the right word?) that format the area outside of this. Could this be affecting my date div tag? Also can I say thanks to all you guys, you're life savers to a beginner like me!

Comment: Use your browsers inspection panel (right click -> inspect element) to see what's going on

Comment: Is there any markup wrapping `$newDate`?

Comment: This is your actual code? If i reproduce this, it works. I guess you have different markup or style, because it's weird and the date should be in the same row as the "Test" text and aligned to the left..

Comment: There's nothing in what you've posted which would indicate *why* the date is not red. There must be some other item in your CSS, PHP, or markup that is causing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

For CSS to take effect the content must be within tags:

```
echo "<span class='subheading'> hello </span>";
```

Will output :

<span class='subheading'> hello </span>

Which can be styled with the following CSS:

```
span.subheading{… … …}
```

In the **echo** statement note the use of alternating double and single quotes to prevent the string closing too early.  They can be used the other way round if you want your html to have the other kind of quotes.

Comment: No, php is rendered before css, when css is rendered, the content of the php is already there.

Answer (score -3):

Use:

```
echo <<< EOT
<div id ="date"> 
    test
    $newDate

</div>
EOT;
```

Comment: This shouldn't be any different than what the OP is already doing. He/She has a different problem.